# Inno Download Plugin - Resizeable?

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

Is it possible to make the Inno Download Plugin wizard page support resizing? It doesn't fit well in Inno 6.

[image: Size of wizard page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `Anchors` properties accordingly after calling `idpDownloadAfter`:

```pascal
idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);

IDPForm.TotalProgressBar.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
IDPForm.FileProgressBar.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
IDPForm.TotalDownloaded.Anchors := [akTop, akRight];
IDPForm.FileDownloaded.Anchors := [akTop, akRight];
IDPForm.DetailsButton.Anchors := [akTop, akRight];
```

[image]